# What extra does [equipment] tag introduce compared to [tools] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

There is the [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag with 103 questions and the [equipment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag with 3.

This question "[Are green plastic bottles suitable for making a cold frame/greenhouse?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/whats-going-on-in-this-picture-old-landscaping-equipment)" could be tagged with [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) instead but the others I am not sure about.

- [What's going on in this picture (old landscaping equipment)?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/whats-going-on-in-this-picture-old-landscaping-equipment)
- [Please Help. I need to plant 10000 Saffron bulbs which is on order. What equipment to use(UK based)](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/please-help-i-need-to-plant-10000-saffron-bulbs-which-is-on-order-what-equipme)

Does [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag stand for hand-held, smaller size tools while [equipment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag is for larger machines, etc.?

I am asking so we can define a tag wiki excerpt for the [equipment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent question.  I think tools is used for hand tools or tools you can pick up.  Equipment would be for, as you say, larger equipment such as compactors, tractors, gas tillers.

Comment: I have proposed edits on the tag wikis and I have borrowed your example list for the equipment tag.